# Python code not printing out solution just blank line

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to code a solution to calculate out all of a numbers factors and then which of them are prime. However, while calculating out sections of the problem i try to use prints as check markers and the prints are all blank and the program runs without stopping so its looping somehow or I'm just asking for to many calculations.
I am still learning so it is most likely something obvious that Ive overlooked.

```
#What is the largest prime factor of the
# number 600851475143 ?

q = 600851475143
factors = [1]
primefactors = []
for i in range(2, 600851475143):
    if q % i == 0:
        list.append(factors, i)
print(factors)

for i in factors:
    if i > 3:
        if i % 6 == 1:
            list.append(primefactors, i)
print(primefactors)
```

Comment: works fine for `q=600` I suspect your program hasn't finished running the 1st loop given that you are using `q=600851475143`. If you put a `print(i)` in the first loop you will see what I mean.

Comment: For reference, pretending that your for loop completes about 1000000 iterations per seconds, it will still take about a week (6.95 days) to complete 600851475143 iterations. It's a big number

Comment: i didn't realize just how much stress i was putting on the calculations for my computer, i have promptly apologized to my computer and comforted it with a de-frag session and a reboot. i will be nicer to it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm isn't efficient because you are iterating over a very large range of numbers. I recommend you use another algorithm:

```
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
    if n % i == 0:
        factors.append(i)
        if all(i % j != 0 for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(i))+1)):
            primefactors.append(i)
```

Now the reason I only iterated from 2 to the square root of the number is because of this:

You can write any number as a * b = n, now this is important because as a and b get closer to each other they will slowly cover each factor on both sides. And once they are both the same number (which means that they are the squareroot of said n) you have basically discovered all the factors of that number. Think of it in this way, consider the number 12; what are its factors?

Well:
1 * 12 --
2 * 6 --
3 * 4 --
4 * 3 --
6 * 2 --
and 12 * 1

Now have you noticed something? After 3 * 4, the closest the two factors can get to each other while being integers; the list is mirrored. This is because you are essentially repeating the list as a mirror after you check factors UNTIL the squareroot(as an integer of course). This is why I used stopped at math.sqrt(n), turned it to an integer to make it a whole number; and then added 1 to the range because a perfect square number would have one of its factors as its square root. For example, if I had only specified the range as 'int(math.sqrt(n))' for the number 36; this program would skip the factor 6.

Also, when you're appending something; you shouldn't say 'list.append()', you should only type in 'append()' as the opposite creates an error in your program. Furthermore, the reason why nothing is being printed lies in the fact that your loop takes too long to complete. It's not that it's faulty, your code is technically correct; it just takes too long to output information.

And this conditional statement 'if i % 6 == 1' isn't correct, if you truly want to check whether a given number is prime or not; you're gonna have to rely on factoring it until it's square root; including of course.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this does help! i knew the math was wrong for calculations for prime numbers but i was more worried about getting any result haha.  so i will start looking into shortcut math to reduce processes that put unnecessary calculations on the computer like the not duplicating work by going over half way. thank you again!